# self vs class name for class methods in inheritance

Tags: ruby, inheritance, class-method

In this code:

```
class Dog
  def self.bark
    print "woof"
  end
end

class Little_dog < Dog
end

Little_dog.bark
```

the method is inherited from a generalised class that references `self`. But the next patch of code:

```
class Dog
  def Dog.bark
    print "woof"
  end
end

class Little_dog < Dog
end

Little_dog.bark
```

also works. I was expecting it to give me an error, but it didn't.

How does `self` refer to the class method under class inheritance? Why does the `little_dog` class have a class method `bark` in the second example when I only defined it as a class method of `Dog`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`self` is widely used in [Ruby Metaprogramming](http://ruby-metaprogramming.rubylearning.com/).

From [Metaprogramming Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356476) book:

> Every line of Ruby code is executed inside an object—the so–called
>   current object. The current object is also known as self, because
>   you can access it with the self keyword.
>
> Only one object can take the role of self at a given time, but no
>   object holds that role for a long time. In particular, when you call a
>   method, the receiver becomes self. From that moment on, all instance
>   variables are instance variables of self, and all methods called
>   without an explicit receiver are called on self. As soon as your code
>   explicitly calls a method on some other object, that other object
>   becomes self.

So, in code:

```
class Dog
  # self represents the class object i.e: Dog. Which is an instance of Class.
  # `bark` will be treated as class method
  def self.bark 
    print "woof"
  end
end
```

can also be written as:

```
class Dog
  # Dog is an instance of Class.
  # `bark` will be treated as class method
  def Dog.bark 
    print "woof"
  end
end
```

Inheritance allows a subclass to use features of its parent class. That's why you can access `bark` method in `Little_dog` class since it is inherited `Dog` class:

```
class Little_dog < Dog
  # has `bark` as a class method because of Dog
end
```

[Ruby style guide tip](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#camelcase-classes): In Ruby it's considered as a best practice to use CamelCase convention for naming classes and modules.

Answer (score 1):

When you're defining class method it actually doesn't matter if you use

```
Dog.bark
```

or

```
self.bark
```

Both method defines class method which will be inherited by subclasses.

Only difference is when you will be changing name of class Dog to something else, like BigDog - when you use  `Dog.bark` it obviously needs to be changed to `BigDog.bark`.

When using `self` method definition, `self.bark` will still work.

Comment: is that typical of all languages? for example python?

Comment: I'm not sure :) You will probably need someone who knows Python better then me to answer this question properly.

Comment: Also: in other contexts (like using ````self```` *within* method) ````self```` and ````Dog```` *aren't* equivalent.